# Exclamation mark inside double quotes results in a strange parse error

Tags: bash, quotes

Why does this command line work:

```
$ output='Irrelevant'; if [[ $output =~ Something ]]; then echo "I found something in the output." ; fi
```

And this one give me a strange parse error?

```
$ output='Irrelevant'; if [[ $output =~ Something ]]; then echo "I found something in the output!" ; fi
-bash: !": event not found
```

The *only* change from the first version is that the sentence to be echoed inside quotes ends with an exclamation mark. **Why does Bash give me that error in the second version?**

In case it matters, this is the output from `bash --version`:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap the string in single quotes instead of double quotes.

The exclamation point invokes the very useful history expansion function described in the [`bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction).

> History expansions are introduced by the appearance of the history expansion character, which is `!` by default. Only `\` and `'` may be used to escape the history expansion character.

For instance, to execute the last command that started with the word `mysql` type this:

```
!mysql
```

or to execute the last command containing the word `grep`, type this:

```
!?grep
```

The `bash` manual also documents the syntax of the [history expansion operators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators).

Comment: I actually knew about the history expansion. But didn't connect the dots. Thanks!